# How to use QuickCheck to test database related functions?

Tags: haskell, persistent, quickcheck

I need to test a lot of functions that access the database (via Persistent). While I can do this using `monadicIO` and `withSqlitePool` it will result in inefficient tests. Each test, not property, but test, will create and destroy the DB pool. How do I prevent this?

**Important:** Forget about efficiency or elegance. I haven't been able to make the `QuickCheck` and `Persistent` types to even compose.

```
instance (Monad a) => MonadThrow (PropertyM a)

instance (MonadThrow a) => MonadCatch (PropertyM a)

type NwApp = SqlPersistT IO

prop_childCreation :: PropertyM NwApp Bool
prop_childCreation = do
  uid <- pick $ UserKey <$> arbitrary
  lid <- pick $ LogKey <$> arbitrary
  gid <- pick $ Aria2Gid <$> arbitrary
  let createDownload_  = createDownload gid lid uid []
  (Entity pid _) <- run $ createDownload_ Nothing
  dstatus <- pick arbitrary
  parent <- run $ updateGet pid [DownloadStatus =. dstatus]

  let test = do 
        (Entity cid child) <- run $ createDownload_ (Just pid)
        case (parent ^. status, child ^. status) of
          (DownloadComplete ChildrenComplete, DownloadComplete ChildrenNone) -> return True
          (DownloadComplete ChildrenIncomplete, DownloadIncomplete) -> return True
          _ -> return False

  test `catches` [
    Handler (\ (e :: SanityException) -> return True),
    Handler (\ (e :: SomeException) -> return False)
    ]

-- How do I write this function?
runTests = monadicIO $ runSqlite ":memory:" $ do 
 -- whatever I do, this function fails to typecheck
```

Comment: Can you give an example of one of your quickcheck properties?

Comment: Don't you just want to use `withSqlitePool` outside of the call to `monadicIO`? E.g., `tests = withSqlitePool $ \pool -> do monadicIO (test1 pool); monadicIO (test2 pool)`.

Comment: We use a SQLite connection to `:memory:` (I think that's more or less just an in-memory SQLite database). It seems to work well enough, certainly enough to never be a bottleneck, but perhaps you are moving more data around than we are. The slow arduous thing you _could_ do is create your own instance of `PersistStore` and implement it with (for example) a bunch of `Data.Map`s. But that absolutely prevents you from using anything in `Database.Persist.Sql`, in which case you would need to spend an arm and a leg to construct a `SqlBackend` value.

Comment: Added the pseuso code for a test. On the mobile right now, will add the actual code from my laptop.

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is an efficient boilerplate that sets up the DB once, maintains a single connection pool, and clears out the DB between tests/properties.

Comment: @RowanBlush I am unable to make it compose even if I pass around the `ConnectionPool` manually. Can you help me with some PoC code? I'm fine even if it type-checks (I'll tackle the elegance later).

Comment: What test framework do you use to run your QuickCheck tests?

Comment: @bennofs nothing, right now. I don't even know if a batteries-included testing framework is available. I'm stuck at a very basic level right now -- trying to get the QuickCheck and Persistent types to compose.

Comment: How do you even clear out the DB with persistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid creating and destroying the DB pool and only set up the DB once, you need to use `withSqliteConn` in your `main` function on the outside and then transform each property to use that connection, like in this code:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show Eq
|]

type SqlT m = SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m))

prop_insert_person :: PropertyM (SqlT IO) ()
prop_insert_person = do
  personName <- pick arbitrary
  personAge  <- pick arbitrary
  let person = Person personName personAge

  -- This assertion will fail right now on the second iteration
  -- since I have not implemented the cleanup code
  numEntries <- run $ count ([] :: [Filter Person])
  assert (numEntries == 0)

  personId <- run $ insert person
  result <- run $ get personId
  assert (result == Just person)

main :: IO ()
main = runNoLoggingT $ withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ \connection -> lift $ do
  let 
    -- Run a SqlT action using our connection
    runSql :: SqlT IO a -> IO a
    runSql =  flip runSqlPersistM connection

    runSqlProperty :: SqlT IO Property -> Property
    runSqlProperty action = ioProperty . runSql $ do
        prop <- action
        liftIO $ putStrLn "\nDB reset code (per test) goes here\n"
        return prop

    quickCheckSql :: PropertyM (SqlT IO) () -> IO ()
    quickCheckSql = quickCheck . monadic runSqlProperty

  -- Initial DB setup code
  runSql $ runMigration migrateAll

  -- Test as many quickcheck properties as you like
  quickCheckSql prop_insert_person
```

The full code including imports and extensions can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bdf989980452569f9098feeb6751ba83).

Note that I did not implement the functionality to clean the database between tests, as I do not know how to do that in general with persistent, you will have to implement that yourself (replace the placeholder cleanup action that just prints a message right now).

---

You should also not need instances for `MonadCatch` / `MonadThrow` for `PropertyM`. Instead, you should catch in the `NwApp` monad. So instead of this:

```
let test = do
  run a
  ...
  run b
test `catch` \exc -> ...
```

you should use the following code instead:

```
let test = do
  a
  b
  return ...whether or not the test was successfull...
let testCaught = test `catch` \exc -> ..handler code...
ok <- test
assert ok
```

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.9.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Property.html#v:ioProperty

Answer (score 2):

( .lhs available at: http://lpaste.net/173182 )

Packages used:

```
build-depends: base >= 4.7 && < 5, QuickCheck, persistent, persistent-sqlite, monad-logger, transformers
```

First, some imports:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

 module Lib2 where

 import Database.Persist.Sql
 import Database.Persist.Sqlite
 import Test.QuickCheck
 import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic
 import Control.Monad.Logger
 import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
```

Here is the query we want to test:

```
 aQuery :: SqlPersistM Int
 aQuery = undefined
```

Of course, `aQuery` may take arguments. The important thing is that
it returns a `SqlPersistM` action.

Here is how you can run a `SqlPersistM` action:

```
 runQuery = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do aQuery
```

Even though `PropertyM` is a monad transformer, it appears that the only
useful way to use it is with `PropertyM IO`.

In order to get an IO-action out of a SqlPersistM-action, we need the
backend.

With these in mind, here is an example database test:

```
 prop_test :: SqlBackend -> PropertyM IO Bool
 prop_test backend = do
   a <- run $ runSqlPersistM aQuery backend
   b <- run $ runSqlPersistM aQuery backend
   return (a == b)
```

Here `run` is the same as `lift`.

To run an SqlPersistM action with a specific backend, we need
to perform some lifting:

```
 runQuery2 = withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ \backend -> do
               liftNoLogging (runSqlPersistM aQuery backend)

 liftNoLogging :: Monad m => m a -> NoLoggingT m a
 liftNoLogging = lift
```

Explanation:

- `runSqlPersistM aQuery backend` is an IO-action
- but `withSqliteConn ...` requires a monadic action that has logging
- so we lift the IO-action to a NoLoggingT IO-action with the `liftNoLogging` function

Finally, to run prop_test via quickCheck:

```
 runTest = withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ \backend -> do
             liftNoLogging $ quickCheck (monadicIO (prop_test backend))
```

Comment: You can use `PropertyM m` even if `m` is not `IO`, by providing a function `m a -> IO a`. See my answer

Comment: Yes - `ioProperty` was the function I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
monadicIO :: PropertyM IO a -> Property
runSqlite ":memory:" :: SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a -> m a
prop_childCreation :: PropertyM NwApp Bool
```

These won't compose. One of these doesn't belong.

```
monadic :: Monad m => (m Property -> Property) -> PropertyM m a -> Property
```

This looks better than `monadicIO`: We can combine this and our requirement to use prop_childCreation into a requirement to produce (m Property -> Property).

```
runSqlite ":memory:" :: SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a -> m a
\f -> monadic f prop_childCreation :: (NwApp Property -> Property) -> Property
```

Rewrite NwApp to ease the looking up:

```
runSqlite ":memory:" :: SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) a -> m a
\f -> monadic f prop_childCreation :: (SqlPersistT IO Property -> Property) -> Property
```

I'll just trust that everything with `T` at the end is a `MonadTrans`, meaning we have `lift :: Monad m => m a -> T m a`. Then we can see that this is our chance to get rid of SqlPersistT:

```
\f g -> monadic (f . runSqlite ":memory:" . g) prop_childCreation :: (IO Property -> Property) -> (SqlPersistT IO Property -> SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) Property) -> Property
```

We'll need to get rid of the IO somewhere again, so monadicIO might help us:

```
\f g -> monadic (monadicIO . f . runSqlite ":memory:" . g) prop_childCreation :: (IO Property -> PropertyT IO a) -> (SqlPersistT IO Property -> SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT m)) Property) -> Property
```

Time for lift to shine! Except that in f we apparently throw the `Property` in `IO Property` away, and on the right we need to "fmap" into the monad argument part of SqlPersistT somehow. Well, we can ignore the first problem and defer the other to the next step:

```
\f -> monadic (monadicIO . lift . runSqlite ":memory:" . f (lift . lift)) prop_childCreation :: ((m a -> n a) -> SqlPersistT m a -> SqlPersist n a) -> Property
```

Turns out this looks just like what `Control.Monad.Morph`'s `MFunctor` provides. I'll just pretend SqlPersistT had an instance of that:

```
monadic (monadicIO . lift . runSqlite ":memory:" . mmorph (lift . lift)) prop_childCreation :: Property
```

[Tada!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCPj4JPbKtA) Good luck in your quest, maybe this'll help a little.

The [exference](https://github.com/lspitzner/exference) project attempts to automate the process I just walked through. I've heard that putting _ whereever I put arguments like f and g will make ghc tell you what type should go there.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, there are multiple mistakes here:

1) `runSqlite` will be executed on every test (perhaps even every `run`?), so the requirement "set up the DB only once" from the question is not satisfied
2) by throwing away the `Property` in `IO Property`, you are essentially throwing away test case itself

Comment: "Important: Forget about efficiency or elegance. I haven't been able to make the QuickCheck and Persistent types to even compose." made it sound like making it typecheck is okay as a first step. But yes, after seeing and inserting commentary about the insufficiencies I thought Id just run with it and see if its instructional. But then I thought this'd remain the only answer for a while.